# How to preload assets in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

My game has a slight "blink" on startup because I am attempting to load a large amount of game assets (several CCScenes and textures) inside of appDidFinishLoading. I've found that trying to load textures or CCScenes asynchronously results in drawing issues (the texture is just a black square). What is the proper way to initialize game assets (not just textures) in cocos2d?

Comment: display a "loading" scene with a loading graphics, then load the remaining assets (asynchronously or not)

Comment: It's strange...I've made a "loading" scene, in which I load my assets in it's init method and then switch scenes in onEnter, yet it still skips...

...wait. Init. Loading. Crap. Hang on!

Comment: why do you swith scenes in OnEnter instead of some callback of asynchronous resource loading?

Comment: Because I was a dumber programmer 14 hours ago. NSOperation, where have you been all my life?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone reading this in the future, there's one thing that may confuse you to look out for: [CCTextureCache addImage:filename] does not work if you put it in an asynchronous thread. Instead, you have to use [CCTextureCache addImageAsync:target:selector]. It prevented me from finding the right solution for a while: Make a "loading" CCScene, which only adds a background image that matches your launch image in its init function. Then, in onEnter, perform your loading using NSOperationQueue. NSOperationQueue is nice, because you can assign dependencies between operations, and use completion blocks for whatever you need (updating a progress bar, etc). Here is a helpful article on using them: http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/

Sample implementation:

```
-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

    NSInvocationOperation *operation1 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadTextures) object:nil];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation2 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadAudio)    object:nil];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation3 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayGame)  object:nil];

    [operation3 addDependency:operation1];
    [operation3 addDependency:operation2];

    [queue addOperation:operation1];
    [queue addOperation:operation2];
    [queue addOperation:operation3];
}
```

Finally, one thing to look out for: When you load your assets asynchronously this way, you may have some "blank" textures. Make sure that any scenes you initialize in such an operation has its textures cached in the previous operation. Also, for some reason, if you are declaring solid color sprites with a method like the following, you have to use a dummy texture (something like a white 1x1 png) that has been cached asynchronously, or it will not work.

```
+(CCSprite *)createCCSpriteWithColor:(ccColor3B)color andSize:(CGSize)size
{   
    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite node]; // Does not work asynchronously
    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"blank.png"]; // Works asynchronously, if texture has been cached asynchronously

    [sprite setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    [sprite setColor:color];
    return sprite;
}
```